# Linked List in java isn't printing all items

Tags: java, printing, linked-list

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to get a name and phone number and store it in a linked list. However, when I'm printing out the list of 3 contacts, only the first contact is being printed. What am I doing wrong?

This is the file that was given to me with the main.

**ContactList.java**

```
public class ContactList
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String name;
      String number;    
      ContactNode contact1;
      ContactNode contact2;
      ContactNode contact3;
      
      System.out.println("Person 1");
      System.out.println("Enter name:");
      name = scnr.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter phone number:");
      number = scnr.nextLine();
      System.out.println("You entered: " + name + ", " + number);
      contact1 = new ContactNode(name, number);
      
      System.out.println("Person 2");
      System.out.println("Enter name:");
      name = scnr.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter phone number:");
      number = scnr.nextLine();
      System.out.println("You entered: " + name + ", " + number);
      contact2 = new ContactNode(name, number);
      
      System.out.println("Person 3");
      System.out.println("Enter name:");
      name = scnr.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter phone number:");
      number = scnr.nextLine();
      System.out.println("You entered: " + name + ", " + number);
      contact3 = new ContactNode(name, number);
      
      ContactNode temp = contact1;
      contact3.insertAfter(contact2);
      contact2.insertAfter(contact1);
      
      System.out.println("CONTACT LIST:");
      
      while (temp!= null)
      {
         temp.printContactNode();
         temp = temp.getNext();
         System.out.println();
      }
   }

}
```

This is the file that I was to implement.

**ContactNode.java**

```
public class ContactNode
{
   private String contactName;
   private String contactPhoneNumber;
   private ContactNode nextNodePtr;
   
   // constructor
   public ContactNode(String name, String num)
   {
       contactName = name;
       contactPhoneNumber = num;
       nextNodePtr = null;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
       return contactName;
   }

   public String getPhoneNumber()
   {
       return contactPhoneNumber;
   }

   public void insertAfter(ContactNode nodeLoc)
   {
       ContactNode tmpNext;

        tmpNext = this.nextNodePtr;
        this.nextNodePtr = nodeLoc;
        nodeLoc = tmpNext;
   }

   public ContactNode getNext()
   {
        return this.nextNodePtr;
   }

   public void printContactNode()
   {
       do
       {
        System.out.println("Name: " + this.contactName);
        System.out.println("Phone number: " + this.contactPhoneNumber);
        this.getNext();
       } while(getNext() != null);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised your `printContactNode` isn't an infinite loop.  Basically this is impossible as you have it.  You call "getNext()" but never do anything with that value it returns.  That can't work.

Comment: In `insertAfter()`, the 3rd statement is wrong: Assigning to `nodeLoc` doesn't do anything. The statement should be: `nodeLoc.nextNodePtr = tmpNext;`

Answer (score 1):

In your do while loop, there isn't any logic to move onto the next contact. Calling `this.getNext()` won't accomplish anything if you're not referencing the result. What you're probably looking for is something like this:

```
ContactNode current = this;
do {
    
    // Print
    current = current.getNext();
} while(current != null);
```

---

To solve problems like this in the future, you should probably take a look at what your code is doing line by line. For example, say we have two contacts (contact 1 and contact 2). Then your code will print the first contact information, then retrieve contact 2 (with `this.getNext()`) but not do anything with it, then check whether `getNext()` (contact 2) is `null`, which it isn't. Then the loop will repeat and the same process will happen again. Your code is never moving on.